# Add optional arguments before and after "Exercise"

Tags: environments, theorems, optional-arguments, exercises

I would like to create an exercise environment for which I can specify two optional arguments, one appearing before the "Exercise" mention and the other one appearing in brackets after the theorem number.

I'm using the `amsthm` package.

Using a basic theorem style such as

```
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}{}{}{}{}{\sffamily\bfseries}{.}{ }{}
\theoremstyle{mystyle}{
    \newtheorem{exo}{\bfseries Exercice}}
```

the following code

```
\begin{exo}[Nom de l'exo]
Montrer par récurrence sur $n$ que
\end{exo}
```

gives me this output:

[image]

In another course, I used a different environment that helped me add something *before* the "Exercise":

```
\newtheoremstyle{exerci}{}{}{}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{\thmnote{#3}~\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{#2}}
\theoremstyle{exerci}
\newtheorem{exo}[]{Exercice}
```

so

```
\begin{exo}[\faBatteryThreeQuarters]
Montrer par récurrence sur $n$ que
\end{exo}
```

gives me the following output:

[image]

Now I can't figure how to allow for *both* optional arguments to appear. Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the use of `theorem` environment mandatory? If not, you could create a `newcommand` with a specific counter and those two arguments. That's what I do for my students.

Comment: No, it isn't at all! How to make these arguments optional though? This might be an easy question but I'm pretty new at creating commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can let a battery name (`bata` to `batd`) or nothing, and let an exercise name or not.

[image: exercise command]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fontawesome}



\newcounter{exer}
    \newenvironment{exercice}[2]
    {
    \addtocounter{exer}{1}
    
    \par\medskip\noindent{\textbf{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\hphantom{\bata}}{#1} Exercice {\theexer}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{.}{ #2.}}}}
    {\par \medskip}
    
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\bata}{\faBatteryQuarter}
    \newcommand{\batb}{\faBatteryHalf}
    \newcommand{\batc}{\faBatteryThreeQuarters}
    \newcommand{\batd}{\faBatteryFull}

    \exercice{\bata}{(Dérivation)}
    
        Montrer que la dérivée de la fonction $x \mapsto x^2$ est la fonction $x\mapsto 2x$.
        
    \exercice{\batb}{(Énoncé)}
    
        Faire ce que vous voulez pendant une demi-heure.
        
    \exercice{\batc}{}
        
        Ici, pas de nom d'exercice.

    \exercice{\batd}{(Comme avant)}
    
    \exercice{}{}
    
        Ici, carrément ni batterie, ni nom.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup ! I still need to get acquainted with the `ifthen` package to fully understand the workaround, but that's exactly what I asked for.

Comment: Another thing: you seem to be calling the environment as if you were using a command, which is a shortcut I didn't know of. I take it that LaTeX understand your  `\exercice{\bata}{(Dérivation)} Blabla` as a `\begin{exercice}{\bata}{(Dérivation)} Blabla` with the difference that it ends the environment by itself... somewhere.
So I'm wondering: where exactly? Only when another `\exo` is called?

(I noticed that the regular way of calling the environment still works in case I really need to specify where I want it to end)

Comment: Yes, you can do both. Here the environment does nothing more than writing the title, so it's ok to call it like a command (even if I don't *know* if it's regular to do it).